# serialize browsing number of URLs using webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I'm using webbrowser control...
This is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string s in URLsList)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(s);

    }

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //Do something
}
```

but how can I serialize browsing of URLs and execute `DocumentCompleted` for each of them?
How can I prevent from conflicts?

Comment: You shouldn't use for each. In button click event navigate first url. Then you should navigate next url end of web browser complete method.

Comment: A similar question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152965/1768303