# How to navigate in a list of links using webbrowser?

Tags: c#, multithreading, url, webbrowser-control

I have a list of url and I need to navigate them. How can I make sure that every url will call the DocumentCompleted event ? I've already tried to create many threads and tried using a single thread too but the app is still not firing the event DocumentCompleted for each url.

Is there a way to make a loop in a list of urls and make them call a DocumentCompleted until the thread calls the next url ?

Comment: why do you want that ?

Comment: Each url has a different text and I need to save those texts. Simple like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement this, [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) and [Task Parallel Library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) may come in handy. They allow to have familiar, pseudo-linear code flow for what is an asynchronous logic (handling `DocumentCompleted` events for multiple navigations, one after another).

I answered a similar question for a **WinForm app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152965/1768303)** and for a **console app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303)**.

If you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.

If C# 5.0 is not available for this project, you can use `yield`, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296644/1768303).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I´m using .net 4.0, so I can´t use async/await. But thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: @galioni, you can use `yield` then, exactly like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22296644/1768303. Or, if you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.

Comment: It's worked in vs2010 with .net 4.0 ! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

If a page has scripts errors on it, it is possible it will never complete. You should make a timeout for that event.