# How to get response from webbrowser control website is responding properly or giving some error

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to check website response like as website is responding properly like it giving some error
like 404 or 505 or its `Internet Explorer not able to find web page` Please give some different or easy answer i already searched in Google..

I'am using Below solution but while using for-loop for more then one link at a time its not working can any one please help me.

```
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri( "SomeRandomUrl");
    ((SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance).NavigateError += new
 SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateErrorEventHandler(Form1_NavigateError);

    void Form1_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Frame, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        int currentStatusCode = (int)StatusCode;</code>
    }
```

Comment: Use `async/await` if you need to handle events in the loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21950328/1768303

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void GetErrorCode(string url)
{
    try
    {
        string htmlString = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
        Console.WriteLine(htmlString);
    }
    catch (WebException webExp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got a {0} error!", (int)((HttpWebResponse) webExp.Response).StatusCode);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Call as follows:

```
GetErrorCode("http://www.gooogle.com/GiveMeA404ErrorPagePlease");
```

Comment: This page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable suggests a variation to `WebClient.DownloadString`, but I don't know if it will matter or not for what you are doing.

Comment: PhatWrat Thanks for reply but all answer u mentioned time consuming that's why i choose web browser control to check its little fast then others please suggest if u hav answer about web browser control.