# How Can Read Web Page Using WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
string urlt = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
Webbrowser1.Navigate("Google.com")

        HtmlElement elem;
        if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML");
            if (elems.Count == 1)
            {
                elem = elems[0];
                string pageSource = elem.InnerHtml;

                if (pageSource == "404" || pageSource == "Inter" || pageSource == "siteblocked")
                {


                }
                else
                {

                    Ret2.Add("Page.." + "Url..." + urlt);

                }
```

Am Using above mentioned code for reading WebPage at "DocumentCompleted" Event But If I am
Using "For loop" for more then one Url It not calling to DocumentCompleted Event everytime Please suggest if any good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to navigate in a list of links using webbrowser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935972/how-to-navigate-in-a-list-of-links-using-webbrowser)

Comment: Noseratio thanks but async or await is not supported i think iam using vs2010 and i already installed [Nuget](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/file/37502/36/NuGet.Tools.vsix) but still iam finding async keyword, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment:

> .. but async or await is not supported i think iam using vs2010 and i
>   already installed Nuget but still iam finding async keyword, please
>   help

If you can't use `async/await`, then you can't use `for` loop for asynchronous `WebBrowser` navigation, unless resorting to deprecated hacks with `DoEvents`. Use the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), that's what C# 5.0 compiler generates behind the scene for `async/await`.

Alternatively, if you're adventurous enough, you can simulate `async/await` with `yield`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22291625/1768303).

**Updated**, below is another way of exploiting the C# enumerator state machine (compatible with C# 2.0 and later):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsForms_22296644
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        IEnumerable GetNavigator(string[] urls, MethodInvoker next)
        {
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler =
                delegate { next(); };

            this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
            try
            {
                foreach (var url in urls)
                {
                    this.webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                    yield return Type.Missing;
                    MessageBox.Show(this.webBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
            }
        }

        void StartNavigation(string[] urls)
        {
            IEnumerator enumerator = null;
            MethodInvoker next = delegate { enumerator.MoveNext(); };
            enumerator = GetNavigator(urls, next).GetEnumerator();
            next();
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartNavigation(new[] { 
                "http://example.com",
                "http://example.net",
                "http://example.org" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your code? Especially I am not quiet clear about how delegates and IEnumerator is working.

Comment: @AbdurRahim, this question is specific to `WebBrowser`. If you need to understand how the compiler-generated `IEnumerator`-based state machine and `yield` work *in general*, check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/10/01/iterator-state-machines.aspx. You may also want to ask this as a separate question.