# Web browser control send event when the page loads

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, .net-2.0

I have an application that takes links from a web page (10 links) and loads each link in a web browser control and when page loads, main form sends an event (from webbrowser_DocumentCompleted) to a class with a html of a loaded page to do the parsing.
I have to pass the messages between main form and the class to notify the class when the html is ready and the class can do its thing.

I am using thread to call the function that takes each link and use AutoResetEvent to wait until the page is loaded so I can move to the next link.

Is there any other (better) way to do this?
It is .NET 2.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a thread just to drive the asynchronous logic. Here is how it can be done for .NET 2.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22296644/1768303

Comment: Why do you use .NET 2.0 in 2014?? Why at least 3.5? There is no reason do not upgrade.

Comment: @Noseratio I can't run the sample code, Action requires 1 type argument.

Comment: @lopkiju, I update the code to target .NET 2.0.