# .NET: Thread exited code 0 using a Webbrowser control and timer

Tags: .net, winforms, timer, webbrowser-control

I have a simple winforms application with a webbrowsercontrol. All it has to do is fill some fields on a page, submit said page, and once the next page is loaded, inspect the HTML on it to gather the results and save them. This processs has to be repeteated N times, given a set of data. Between each process, the app has to wait for a few seconds, so the user can have a look at the results in the browser.

The application seems to work fine for a while. However, at some point, it eventually freezes, no exceptions raised, all i get is a "thread exited with code 0 (0x0)" in the results window on visual studio.

I'm kinda lost, any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643/1768303) is doing exactly what you're after. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152965/1768303) is also relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately, async/await features are not an option, This must work on 4.0 at the most...

Comment: If you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.